# How far can I go with this program of computing prime numbers?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int ifprime(long long int);
int main()

{
    long long int number;   
    cout<<"Enter the number of prime numbers you want to know:\n";
    cin>>number;    //number is the number of prime numbers to be displayed
    long long int j=0;
    long long int m=2;      //m would be used as consecutive natural numbers on which, test of prime number is performed

    while (1<2)
    {
        if(ifprime(m)==1)
        {
            j+=1;   // j is the counter of the prime numbers found and displayed
            cout<<m<<endl;
        }
        m+=1;
        if(j==number)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}

int ifprime(long long int a)
{
    for(int i=2;i<a;i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The range of `long long int` seems to be small compared to the biggest primes known :/

Even if I were to compute the last prime number in the range of the `long long int` , can I compute the time it would take to compute that number?

Comment: Just a trick : ifprime should be return "bool" instead of arbitrary value representing a boolean state

Comment: Hint: you could make `ifprime` twice as fast by testing only odd numbers.

Comment: The largest prime smaller than 2^63-1 is 9223372036854775783. If you could do one loop iteration per nanosecond it would take almost three hundred years for `ifprime` to find it. The largest prime in an *unsigned* 64-bit int would take almost six hundred years. (Note that using `int` in the loop is a bug.)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, perhaps

Comment: You can compute the complexity: `O(Pn²)` (with `Pn` the `n`*th* prime number).

Comment: Other hint: you can optimize more by makeing your loop stop at `a/2` rather than at `a` (or even better at the square root of `a`). So you'll cut the time from 600 to 150 years.

Comment: This is really a question on mathematics. I suggest you read the answers over at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272791/how-many-prime-numbers-are-known

Comment: @MichaelWalz I understand the /2 part but didn't understand the square root of a part  :/  .. If you would please explain

Comment: @brainst it's really very basic maths.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the biggest prime number was `n = 13`. Your program would then try the following numbers: `2, 3, 4,.. 11, 12`
So you have to test your number n - 2 times (which is more or less n times) and until you reach that point your program has to go through `2, 3, 4, ... 11, 12, 13`, which is also (more or less) n times. `-->`The complexity is `O(n^2)`.
Simple tip to speed up your program: store every prime number you've found so far in `std::vector` and only try these. This way you avoid integer factorization (like dividing with 6 (2 * 3) or 8 (2 * 2 * 2)).